# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los elementos de una lista circular que coincidan con un párametro?

Tags: java, lista

de ante manos gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.
Tengo la necesidad de elaborar un método en Java donde imprima los elementos que coincidan con un parámetro determinado, en este caso tengo la necesidad de elaborar el método.

```
public void mostrar(int precio) {
}
```

De esta manera necesito que se muestren los elementos con un precio menor o igual al indicado.

Tengo una clase llamada Lista_circular donde tengo desarrollados distintos métodos.

```
public class Lista_circular {
private Nodo cabeza, ultimo;


//Método encargado de insertar juegos en la lista circular
public void inserta(Juego j){
//si el valor de cabeza es nulo, es decir, la lista está vacía el juego
//toma el valor de j
if (cabeza == null){
    cabeza = new Nodo (j); 
    //a la vez el último es el primero dentro de la lista
    ultimo = cabeza;
    //se establece que el ultimo tiene como siguiente a cabeza
    ultimo.setNext(cabeza);
//si ya hay un valor en cabeza al momento de agregar un juego
}else{
    //el juego a ingresar se acomoda de tal manera que el precio menor 
    //vaya a la izquierda del ya ingresado         
    if(j.getPrecio() < cabeza.getDato().getPrecio()){
        //se crea un aux para unir los juegos
        Nodo aux = new Nodo (j); 
        aux.setNext(cabeza);
        cabeza = aux;
        //con esto hacemos la lista circular   
        ultimo.setNext(cabeza); 
        //para insertar todos los datos mayor
    }else{ 
        //valida si el precio del nuevo juego a insertar tiene un precio
        //mayor al último ingresado
        if (j.getPrecio() >= ultimo.getDato().getPrecio()){ 
            //No se pueden unir nodos y juegos, por ello crearemos el nodo auxiliar
            Nodo aux = new Nodo (j);
            ultimo.setNext(aux);
            ultimo = aux; 
            ultimo.setNext(cabeza); //circular de nuevo 
            //para insertar en el medio de la estructura
        }else{ 
            Nodo aux = cabeza;
            while(j.getPrecio() > aux.getNext().getDato().getPrecio() ){ //el precio del juego es mayor al siguiente del auxiliar
                aux = aux.getNext(); 
            }
            Nodo temp = new Nodo (j); //creamos el dato temporal para guardar el juego entre dos precios, una vez cerrado el ciclo
            //se une primero el juego menor con el mayor para no perder la listya
            temp.setNext(aux.getNext());
            aux.setNext(temp); //se une el menor con el mayor en dicha comparacion
        }  
    }
}

//Método encargado de validar si un juego existe dentro de la lista
public boolean existe (String nombre){
String mensaje;
boolean existe = false;
Nodo aux = cabeza;
if (cabeza == null) {
    mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos";
} else {
    if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
        existe = true;
    }
    aux = aux.getNext();
    while (aux != cabeza) {
        if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
}
return existe;
}

//Método encargado de moficiar en base a nombre y plataforma
public void modifica (String nombre, String plataforma){
String mensaje = "";
boolean existe = false;
Nodo aux = cabeza;
if (cabeza == null) {
    mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
}
else {
    if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre()) && plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma()) ){
        aux.getDato().setPuntaje(10);
        existe = true;
    }
    aux = aux.getNext();
    while (aux != cabeza) {
        if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre()) && plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma()) ) {
            aux.getDato().setPuntaje(10);
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
}
if (existe == false) {
    System.out.println("No existe un juego con las caracteristicas indicadas");
}
}

//Método encargado de eliminar en base a categoria y nombre
public void elimina (String categoria, String nombre){
String mensaje = "";
boolean existe = false;
Nodo aux = cabeza;
if (cabeza == null) {
    mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
} else {
    if (categoria.equals(aux.getDato().getCategoria()) && nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
        cabeza = aux.getNext();
        ultimo.setNext(cabeza);
        existe = true;
    } else if (categoria.equals(aux.getDato().getCategoria()) && nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
        aux.setNext(aux.getNext().getNext());
        existe = true;
    }
    aux = aux.getNext();
    while (aux != cabeza) {
        if (categoria.equals(aux.getDato().getCategoria()) && nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
            aux.setNext(aux.getNext().getNext());
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
}
if (existe == false) {
    System.out.println("No existe un juego que coincida con la categoria y nombre indicados");
}
}

//Método encargado de contar los elementos que coincidan con plataforma
public int contar (String plataforma){
String mensaje = "";
boolean existe = false;
Nodo aux = cabeza;
int cont = 0;
if (cabeza == null) {
    mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
}else{                        
    if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())){
        cont++;
        existe = true;
    } else {
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())) {                        
                existe = true;  
            }
            cont++;
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
            }
    if (existe == false) {
        System.out.println("No existen juegos de dicha plataforma");
        return 0;
        }                        
    }
return cont;
}
```

De esta manera tengo el siguiente método con el cual tengo inconvenientes ya que no entiendo muy bien cómo imprimir en consola los juegos que tengan como parámetro precio un valor menor o igual al indicado

```
public void mostrar(int precio) {
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    int cont = 0;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    } else {
        if (precio <= aux.getDato().getPrecio()) {                
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (precio <= aux.getDato().getPrecio()) {
                existe = true;
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        if (existe == false) {
            System.out.println("No existen juegos de dicha plataforma");
        }
    }
}
```

Se que el método no hace mucho a nivel lógico y de ahí me gustaría que me ayudarán a entender como hacerlo.

Como datos adicional dentro del main llamo los distintos métodos de la siguiente manera.

```
Lista_circular lista = new Lista_circular();
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Deportes", "PES 2015", "PS3", 30, 7.8f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "God of War SAGA", "PS3", 40, 8.7f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Supervivencia", "The Last of US", "PS3", 60, 9.2f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "GTA V", "PS3", 60, 8.3f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Indie", "Inside + Limbo", "PS4", 70, 8.3f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "Bioshock - The Collection", "PS4", 55, 9.0f));
    //Lista circular original
    System.out.println("---LISTA ORIGINAL---");
    System.out.println(lista.toString());
    //Buscar un juego con el nombre
    System.out.println("---BUSQUEDA DE JUEGO BASADO EN EL NOMBRE---");
    System.out.println("¿El juego ingresado existe? \n"+lista.existe("PES 2018"));
    System.out.println("\n");
    //Modifica el puntaje de un juego dado un nombre y plataforma
    System.out.println("---MODIFICACIÓN DEL PUNTAJE BASADO EN 2 CAMPOS---");
    System.out.println("Modificación del puntaje dado un juego y plataforma 
dado");
    lista.modifica("Inside + Limbo", "PS4");
    System.out.println("Lista después de modificación:\n" + lista);        
    //Elimina un juego dada una categoría y un nombre
    System.out.println("---ELIMINACIÓN DE JUEGO BASADO EN EL NOMBRE---");
    System.out.println("Elimina por ID");
    lista.elimina("Deportes", "PES 2015");
    System.out.println("Lista después de eliminación:\n"+lista);
    //Indica cuantos juegos existen de una plataforma
    System.out.println("---CONTEO DE JUEGOS SEGÚN PLATAFORMA---");
    System.out.println("Para la plataforma indicada se encontraron: "  
+lista.contar("PS3"));
    //Muestra la cantidad de juegos con un precio menor o igual
    System.out.println("MUESTREO DE JUEGOS SEGÚN PRECIO");
    System.out.println(lista.toString());       
}
}
```

Comment: No tengo claro cuál es el problema, lo único que falta es que si en el bucle while encuentras un elemento que cumple la condición, además de poner existe a true, muestres en la consola el elemento que la cumple

Answer (score 0):

La implementacion del metodo es similar a todos los recorridos que ya estas implementando:

```
if(cabeza == null) {
    //lista vacia
    return;
}
Nodo aux = cabeza;
if(/* condicion */) {
    /* realizar algo */
}
aux = aux.getNext();

while (aux != cabeza) {
    if (/* condicion */) {
        /* realizar algo */
    }
    aux = aux.getNext();
}
```

Para el caso particular que consultas, la condicion seria `aux.getDato().getPrecio() < precio` y lo que hagas con el juego, problablemente sea `System.out.println(aux.getDato())`

Te recomiendo que cuando veas repeticion de codigo intentes eliminarla, en el codigo anterior la condicion y el realizar algo se repite 2 veces, eso puede conllevar a error si es que se realizan cosas distintas o si se comprueba la condicion de forma distinta.

Se puede reescribir facilmente como:

```
if(cabeza == null) {
    //lista vacia
    return;
}
Nodo aux = cabeza;
do {
    if (/* condicion */) {
        /* realizar algo */
    }
    aux = aux.getNext();
}
while (aux != cabeza);
```

De esta forma minimizas el error humano, como el que cometiste por ejemplo en el metodo `public int contar (String plataforma)`. El contador de juegos de la plataforma no funciona del todo bien.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya se ha mencionado, para imprimir los elementos, lo que necesitas hacer es recorrer la lista e ir imprimiendo los elementos que pertenecen a ella.

Sin embargo, hay una opción más general, que yo prefiero: en vez de recorrer la lista e imprimir cada uno de los elementos, se puede aprovechar el método `String toString()` ya definido en `Object`. De esta forma, se recorre la lista y solo se añade la representación de los elementos a la de la lista.

```
public String toString() {
    if (elementos == 0) return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    String separador = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    recorre(e -> {
        sb.append(e.toString());
        sb.append(separador);
    });

    sb.delete(sb.length() - separador.length(), sb.length());

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Como se puede observar, en vez de recorrer la lista manualmente, he recurrido a un método `recorre`, que implementa un recorrido por la lista, y por cada elemento de ella ejecuta una acción. De esta forma, he implementado un iterador que puede servir para cualquier tipo de recorrido, con lo que ya no hace falta repetir su código.

```
public void recorre(Consumer<Juego> c) {
    if (elementos == 0) return;
    if (c == null) return;

    Nodo<Juego> nodo = cabeza;
    for (int i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
        c.accept(nodo.getElemento());
        nodo = nodo.getSiguiente();
    }
}
```

Como se puede observar, he utilizado interfaces funcionales y expresiones lambda de Java 8. Sin embargo, se puede conseguir el mismo resultado sustituyendo la expresión lambda en la llamada por una clase anónima que implemente la interfaz requerida para el método.

La llamada necesaria para imprimir la lista sería así.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListaCircular lista;
    /* Se omite la creación de la lista */
    System.out.println(lista.toString());
}
```